# Absolute continuity of a measure in the intervals implies absolute continuity of borel measures?

Tags: measure-theory, absolute-continuity, monotone-class-theorem

Suppose I have two positive Borel measures on $[0,\infty]$, say $\mu$ and $\nu$ and I know that $\nu([0,x]) = 0$ implies $\mu([0,x]) = 0$ for any $x$ and that $\nu((a,b]) = 0$ implies $\mu((a,b]) = 0$ for any pair $a,b$.

Does this imply that $\mu < < \nu$? I would think so but I have trouble proving it, I thought that the monotone class theorem was the answer but I don't see how the sets with the property $\nu(E) = 0 \Longrightarrow \mu(E) = 0$ are closed under monotone intersections.

We may assume that the measures are finite, if that helps anything.

Comment: Does your definition of Borel measure require the measure to be locally finite? We run into issues if we allow things like the counting measure. Specifically, let $\nu(\{1\}) = 0$, everywhere else let $\nu$ be the counting measure, and let $\mu$ be the counting measure. Then $\nu$ is never $0$ on an interval, so absolute continuity on intervals is vacuously satisfied. But $\mu(\{1\}) = 1$, so $\mu$ is not absolutely continuous with respect to $\nu$.

Comment: Yes, locally finite. But I would be really happy if this was true even for finite measures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The situation is even worse than my comment. Take any measure $\nu$ that's never $0$ on a nondegenerate interval (the Lebesgue measure works, as do many finite measures). If $\nu$ has sets of measure $0$, then take one such set $E$, let $\lambda$ be a probability measure on $E$, and let $\mu = \nu + \lambda$. Then $\mu$ and $\nu$ satisfy the condition on intervals, but $\mu$ is not absolutely continuous with respect to $\nu$.

Comment: +1.  To check absolute continuity, it is not enough to check it on intervals.